# Getting exception while running multi-tenance code using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am trying to run a multi-tenancy example following [this link](https://gist.github.com/dipold/5700724)

But, executing the code I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

It is coming at

```
connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
```

and even commenting the above line, the same exception is coming at

```
connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
```

Please provide your valuable inputs.

Comment: Are you sure you got your dialect right? The tutorial seems to be made for Postgres SQL, but you seem to be using Oracle.

Comment: yes, that change has been done by me. is the above SET SCHEMA command compatible with ORACLE??

Comment: According to their [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html) it is. Hibernate should have a setting somewhere which will emit the SQL code it is translating the HSQL to. I think that that would help you better solve the problem.

Comment: the setting is to set `org.hibernate.SQL` logger in DEBUG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is not correct. It is "alter session set current_schema".